# How to insert a deleted row in another table

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, delete-row

I have a table `users`.
I want whenever I (or a script) deletes one of this users, that the deleted row is inserted into another `user_deleted` table.

The `users_deleted` tables is exactly the same as the `users` table + a datetime column with NOW() for the deletion time.

For that, i've found the MySQL trigger functionality very handy, sadly it doesn't work like excepted.

[image]

Thing is, when there is a deletion on the `users`, in `users_delete` a blank new row is inserted.

What may be the problem here ?

Comment: I guessed out that since `NEW.` prefix exist for trigger, it also might exist a `OLD.` one that I did not know. And it did the trick, like this:

```sql
BEGIN
INSERT INTO users_deleted (datetime, id, name) VALUES (NOW(), OLD.id, OLD.name);
END
```

Comment: "Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger...In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated. " - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be selecting old values that should be inserted to another table inside the trigger code.

```
INSERT INTO users_deleted (datetime, id, name)
VALUES (NOW(), OLD.id, OLD.name);
```